# streaming data into std::vector<double> crashes

Tags: c++, vector, marshalling, dllexport

I have a C++ DLL that takes streaming data and stores it in a series of `std::vector`s. An additional function then dumps it into an XML. I am calling these functions and sending the data, from C#. The problem is, as I stream the data, it gets to a certain size, then crashes every time.

Code: //vector initialize.

```
std::vector<double> transX;
std::vector<double> transY;
std::vector<double> transZ;
std::vector<double> rotX;
std::vector<double> rotY;
std::vector<double> rotZ;
std::vector<int> frames;
std::vector<string> vTimecode;

//data streams in here and pushes into vectors
__declspec(dllexport) void SetData(double txIN, double tyIN, double tzIN, double rxIN, double ryIN, double rzIN, const char *timecode)
{
    frames.push_back(number);
    transX.push_back(txIN);
    transY.push_back(tyIN);
    transZ.push_back(tzIN);
    rotX.push_back(rxIN);
    rotY.push_back(ryIN);
    rotZ.push_back(rzIN);
    vTimecode.push_back(timeCode);
    number += 1;
}
```

When the vector size reaches 3402, the program crashes with:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The max size of a string vector is 153,391,689, and this is the smallest. Why would this be happening?

The C#:

```
[DllImport("XmlRecord.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetData(double txIN, double tyIN, double tzIN, double rxIN, double ryIN, double rzIN, string TimeCode);

public void Recording(EventArgs args, Processor dproc)
{
    double tx = args.result[0].mid.X;
    double ty = args.result[0].mid.Y;
    double tz = args.result[0].mid.Z;
    double rx = args.result[0].rotation.X;
    double ry = args.result[0].rotation.Y;
    double rz = args.result[0].rotation.Z;
  
    string TimeCode = (dproc.tcHour.ToString() + ":" +
                       dproc.tcMinutes.ToString() + ":" + 
                       dproc.tcSeconds.ToString() + ":" +
                       dproc.tcFrames.ToString());
   
    SetData(tx, ty, tz, rx, ry, rz, TimeCode);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're doing any vector operations concurrently, without protecting the vectors with a mutex?

Comment: How are you getting the const char * that you're sending to the SetData() function? Have you checked that is a valid pointer on your crashing call of that function?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.The only operation involving the vector is the push_back. Should i be using mutex for every push_back?  The data I am sending in is valid as it leaves the c# function, I can print it without issue.

Comment: if the const char *timecode ever happens to be == nullptr, an Access Violation crash would be expected in the std::string ctor as it attempts to dereference the pointer.

Comment: oops, you are calling push_back(TimeCode) not push_back(timecode). But then it's not clear where the TimeCode is coming from.

Comment: To avoid any crash in the vTimecode line, the timecode pointer must be not NULL; must point to legal memory address; the string it points to must be a C-string, that is, NULL-terminated.

Comment: sorry that was a Typo. fixed now!

Comment: Show us how you call the function

Comment: I have added the C#. thanks!

Comment: The other function does not run until the 'Setdata' function stops. There is only one thread in the dll.

Comment: Ah. I was starting the thread in a loop, so it was trying to start again and again. As I suspected, human error. Thanks again for your help all.

Answer (score -1):

While this doesn't fix your crashing problem this is a stylistic concern.

If you are able to change it then I would change from multiple vectors to an object and have a single vector.

So you would have:

```
struct MyObject {
  double transX;
  double transY;
  double transZ;
  double rotX;
  double rotY;
  double rotZ;
  int frame;
  string vTimecode;
};
std::vector<MyObject> objects;
```

and the insert routine becomes

```
  __declspec(dllexport) void SetData(double txIN, double tyIN, double tzIN, double rxIN, double ryIN, double rzIN, const char *timecode)
  {
    MyObject object;
    object.frame = number;
    object.transX = txIN;
    object.transY = tyIN;
    object.transZ = tzIN;
    object.rotX = rxIN;
    object.rotY = ryIN;
    object.rotZ = rzIN;
    object.vTimecode = timeCode;

    objects.push_back(object);
    number += 1;
```

Easier to understand, no?  Also accessing data and deleting objects are easier.